# Django error: value must be either True or False

Tags: django, django-models

I'm currently having this error message on django: ["*** value must be either True or False."]
It's really strange that I could not found where's the bug

#### manager.py

## models.py

```py
from django.contrib.auth.base_user import BaseUserManager


class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
    use_in_migrations = True

    def _create_user(self, username, password, email, **extra_fields):
        if not username or not password or not email:
            raise ValueError("All values must be filled!")
        if not password:
            raise ValueError("Password could not be empty!")
        user = self.model(username=username, email=email, **extra_fields)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_user(self, username, password, **extra_fields):
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff', False)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', False)
        return self._create_user(username, password, **extra_fields)

    def create_superuser(self, username, password, **extra_fields):
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff', True)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', True)

        if extra_fields.get('is_staff') is not True:
            raise ValueError('Superuser must have is_staff=True.')
        if extra_fields.get('is_superuser') is not True:
            raise ValueError('Superuser must have is_superuser=True.')

        return self._create_user(username, password, **extra_fields)
```

#### models.py

```py
import hashlib
import uuid

from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from django.db import models
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver
from rest_framework.authtoken.models import Token

import server.settings as settings
from user.manager import UserManager



STATUS_CHOICES = (
    (0, "禁用"),
    (1, "启用"),
)


class Users(AbstractUser):
    userid = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, verbose_name="用户ID", help_text="用户ID")
    username = models.CharField(max_length=150, unique=True, db_index=True, verbose_name="用户账号",
                                help_text="用户名")
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=255, verbose_name="邮箱", null=True, blank=True, help_text="邮箱")
    avatar = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name="头像", null=True, blank=True, help_text="头像",
                              default="https://api.vvhan.com/api/qt?qq=771151240")
    VIP_CHOICES = (
        (0, "普通用户"),
        (1, "VIP用户"),
    )
    vip = models.IntegerField(
        choices=VIP_CHOICES, default=0, verbose_name="是否VIP", null=False, blank=False, help_text="是否VIP"
    )
    last_login = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True, verbose_name="最后一次登录时间",
                                      help_text="最后一次登录时间", auto_now=True)
    create_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, verbose_name="创建时间", help_text="创建时间")
    update_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, verbose_name="更新时间", help_text="更新时间")
    status = models.IntegerField(
        choices=STATUS_CHOICES, default=1, verbose_name="状态", null=False, blank=False, help_text="状态")
    last_token = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name="最后一次登录Token",
                                  help_text="最后一次登录Token")

    objects = UserManager()

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "用户"
        verbose_name_plural = verbose_name
        ordering = ["-create_time"]

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(args, kwargs)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username

    def set_password(self, raw_password):
        super().set_password(hashlib.md5(raw_password.encode(encoding="UTF-8")).hexdigest())
        return True

    def check_password(self, raw_password):
        password = hashlib.md5(raw_password.encode(encoding="UTF-8")).hexdigest()
        return super().check_password(password)

    def get_avatar(self):
        if self.avatar:
            return self.avatar
        else:
            return "https://api.vvhan.com/api/qt?qq=771151240"

    def get_username(self):
        return self.username

    def get_email(self):
        return self.email

    def clear_token(self):
        self.last_token = None
        self.save()
        return True


@receiver(post_save, sender=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
def create_auth_token(instance=None, created=False, **kwargs):
    """
    Args:
        instance:
        created:
        **kwargs:

    Returns:
        None
    """
    if created:
        Users.objects.create(user=instance)
        Token.objects.create(user=instance)
        Users.objects.filter(user=instance).update(last_token=Token.objects.get(user=instance).key)
    else:
        pass
```

#### views.py

```py
try:
            username = request.data.get('username')
            password = request.data.get('password')
            email = request.data.get('email')
            print(username, password, email)
            if username is None or password is None or email is None:
                return Response({'error': ''}, status=400, content_type='application/json', exception=True)
        except TypeError:
            return Response({'error': ''}, status=400, content_type='application/json', exception=True)
        try:
            Users.objects.create_user(username=username, password=password, email=email)
        except KeyError:
            return Response({'error': KeyError}, status=400, content_type='application/json', exception=True)
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            return Response({'error': e, 'msg': 'server error'}, status=400, content_type='application/json', exception=True)
        user_obj = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        if user_obj:
            token, created = Token.objects.get_or_create(user=user_obj)
            return Response(data, status=200, content_type='application/json', headers={'Authorization': token.key})
        else:
            return Response({'error': 'server error'}, status=500, content_type='application/json', exception=True)`
```

### When the Register API was using under a post method it appears:

```json
["“{'username': 'test', 'email': '1@test.com', 'is_staff': False, 'is_superuser': False}” value must be either True or False."]
Bad Request: /users/register/
[17/Aug/2023 20:57:02] "POST /users/register/ HTTP/1.1" 400 167
```

What i currently expect is that the api could work properly and return userid and token in json